# v-model is not working in vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2

I have a `form` field like below

```
<input type="text" :value="addressObj.name" v-model="dname">
```

It is not working. But below code is working

```
<input type="text" :value="addressObj.name">
```

I have `data()` like below

```
data() {
     return  { 
        dname: '',
     }
},
```

Here I am iterating over `addressObj`. `addressObj.name` is a value of that `addressObj` object. When I add `v-model="dname"` it is creating the issue. I have no issue with `addressObj.name`.

Why `v-model` is not working here ?

Comment: what is `name`?

Comment: Thanks @samayo.  `name` is a data variable. Thanks.

Comment: It's working for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/1bLq21j8/

So if it's not working must be for the iteration. Include it in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first things first : you cannot use `:value` and `v-model` at the same time, `v-model` will always have priority.

What you can do is something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/sx0yjge2/5/

Or if you don't need to have a model attached : https://jsfiddle.net/sx0yjge2/3/